# Custom webpart issue in sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

After configuring the **alternet access mapping** custom web part is not displaying in the site, while clicking link for webpart
    throwing exception:

```
 The "webpart5" Webpart appears to be causing a problem. Exception has been thrown by the  target of an invocation.
Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page temprarily close Web parts or remove
personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator.
```

Pls help somebody how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It obviously is the problem with AAM setting. Check how are you accessing the site in web Part. Is it using SPContext ? Or you are instantiating the new SPWeb object. If you are instantiang the new object, check which zone you are referring to.

Post the web part code if possible.